# Add username token to Axis2 Web service (Which is not running in axis 2 engine)

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, ws-security, rampart

I have created a web service using Maven2 WSDL2Code Plug-in in axis.

```
    https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/maven-plugins/maven-wsdl2code-plugin.html

    Which create a .war file as build result and which is running on the tomcat server and it does not need to deploy into axis2 engine. Since I have done a mapping in "web.xml" file as bellow.


    -web.xml-

     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
      version="3.0">
      <display-name>MavenAxis2WS</display-name>
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
      version="3.0">
      <display-name>MavenAxis2WS</display-name>
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>

-services.xml-

<module ref="rampart"/>
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="UsernameTokenOverHTTPS" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
        <wsp:ExactlyOne>
          <wsp:All>
            <sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
              <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:TransportToken>
                  <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false"/>
                  </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:TransportToken>
                <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                  <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:Basic256/>
                  </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                <sp:Layout>
                  <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:Lax/>
                  </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:Layout>
                <sp:IncludeTimestamp wsp:Optional="true"/>
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:TransportBinding>
            <sp:SignedSupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient" />
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:SignedSupportingTokens>
            <ramp:RampartConfig xmlns:ramp="http://ws.apache.org/rampart/policy">
                <ramp:passwordCallbackClass>security.rampart.PWCBHandler</ramp:passwordCallbackClass>
            </ramp:RampartConfig>
          </wsp:All>
        </wsp:ExactlyOne>
    </wsp:Policy>
```

So here; to where should I put the Rampart module (Since I don't use Axis2.war here)?
Is there any maven dependencies that I can use here for Rampart module?